# Programmatically enable/disable market auto-update

Tags: android

I've seen some applications that automatically install with auto-update ticket, while most don't.

Unfortunately I haven't had much success with finding details on this so I don't have much to offer in the way of explaining what I tried.

How is this accomplished?

Comment: Seems that this is done via some method only available on rooted devices.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Its up to the user, you can't control that as a developer.  Also, the auto update won't work if the permissions have changed.

Comment: I've seen a few applications set as automatic update without me setting it. Each time I uncheck it, I verify that it stays unchecked. However after the next update, it's back to automatic update.

I'm wondering how it is possible for this to happen.

Comment: From what I could gather, the apps only do this on a "rooted" device so I suspect it's happening through a non-normally accessible process. I'll mark your response as the answer.