# Disable Auto Update programmatically in Android 3 (Honeycomb)

Tags: android

I'm new to Android and I'm developing an app which requires the auto update for the software update in the settings should be disabled and by programmatically.

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: This seems not to be possible.

Look here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7355917/programatically-enable-disable-market-auto-update