# How can I programmatically disable automatic updates from Google? (Ice Cream Sandwich)

Tags: android

My company makes a tablet Android app to control an industrial process.   We had been using a Galaxy Tab 10.1, but as that's no longer available in the US we're evaluating the Galaxy Tab **2** 10.1, running 4.03.    We ship the tablet pre-installed with our app, and the app is carefully tested with the version of Android software running on the tablet.

As I was setting up one of the new tablets the setup wizard put up a message saying "*You agree that your tablet may receive and install updates from Google*"     It wasn't asking me, it was **telling** me; there was no place to say "no" or disagree.   Auto update is DISabled in settings.

How can I programmatically prevent a force-feed update to the tablet?    Our users are connected to a local area net because the tablets are used to control other industrial products, but there is **never** any need to connect to the web beyond the factory walls, but we have no way to enforce that on our customers.    The risk is that Google could force a change onto the tablet that might break our app.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The issue may not be software/programming related, so you may want to check out http://android.stackexchange.com/, a stack exchange site for android users.

Comment: My guess is that it is not optional because in the event of more patent bickering they may at anytime need to push out an update in order to comply with a new ruling. And if you want to prevent this you are likely going to have to install a 3rd party ROM on the device.

Comment: i would consider blocking the update server on the network (wifi or whatever it is)

Comment: Why wouldn't it be software/programming related?    I'm asking how to programmatically limit access to my device, or at least display an alert to users when an attempt is made.   There are no other apps installed on the system as we root the tablets before shipping to remove other apps.

Comment: @Vince Lowe - we have no control over how our users configure their networks.   Most of our users DO block outside access because of their own security concerns but there's no guarantee of this.     But I assume Android has a class for network services that would, for instance, allow us to block certain ports.

Comment: @user316117 It seemed like something that should be controllable by a user, but now I get the context of the question. good luck.

Comment: @user316117 can you pragmatically block it by adding the update server to /system/etc/hosts? probably not unless routed I guess

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How can I programmatically prevent a force-feed update to the tablet?

Build your own firmware and use that rather than the stock firmware.

> The risk is that Google could force a change onto the tablet that might break our app.

The risk of blocking the firmware updates is that Samsung (not Google) could deliver an update to the tablet that fixes flaws in the firmware that your customers would appreciate (e.g., better WiFi connectivity).

Please understand that the devices that you are using are *consumer* devices. Such devices are not intended for use "to control an industrial process". The expectation is that if you are using Android in such settings, that you would source your own device and have control over your firmware. Alas, there is not a whole lot of support for that at the moment, [something I blogged about recently](http://commonsware.com/blog/2012/07/05/who-will-become-androids-red-hat.html).

Comment: Thanks.   I spoke to Romain Guy at AnDevIII in SF in May about this and he indicated that he/Google have also gotten feedback to this effect.  Their original expectation was that someone would come out with a ROM for industrial/enterprise use because it's not really reasonable to expect small companies like ours to develop our own custom ROMs.  But since this has not happened companies like us are stuck using what's available.   Your blog entry nails it perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

As long as you target your desired API, an update to the system should not break any functionality of your app.  To answer your question, you cannot programatically disable automatic updates, it is a user function.

Check this link as well: [Programatically enable/disable market auto-update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7355917/programatically-enable-disable-market-auto-update)

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by a "user function".   I'm not worried about the user requesting an update.because he'll know that this might break the app.

Comment: User function, as in, the user is the only one able to edit that setting.