# How to check if user set manual update or auto-update in Android

Tags: android

In our Android app we want to check whether user selected manual update or auto-update for our app. Can we read such information or not?
We want this to control critical updates for our app.

Comment: Nope that is not possible for now . check this link [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7355917/programatically-enable-disable-market-auto-update][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7355917/programatically-enable-disable-market-auto-update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually there is no way to know whether the user has selected manual update or auto update, but we developers sometimes want the users to force update all the apps, (may be because of API change or something like that), the best way to do this is

1. On starting of your app, do an API call and check for an integer, hard code that same number value on your app.
2. If the integer matches allow the user to proceed
3. Once you want the user to force the update, change the value of the integer on your API, so the method will return you false.
4. If the return value is false Show dialog that is not able to dismiss or close and ask them to update, and change the value of the integer in your next APK.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, if you are using a check box option in your xml then you can check whether the check box value is true or not. Imagine you have two check box, One for manual update and other for auto update.

You can save the value of this checkbox to a Sharedpreference and then through a web service call you can check that your user is using manual or auto update.

Comment: I mean auto-update check settings that are set inside Play Store for our app, not inside our app settings.